# Positioning a DIV correct method?

Tags: css, html

I am playing with DIVs and want to know best method on how to achieve something.

I want to get following result:

```
                   ------------------------------|
                   |           DIV 1             |
                   ------------------------------|
                      | DIV 2 |          | DIV 3||
                      ---------          --------|
                                                 |  << Far right of web page
```

Basically want DIV 1 to appear on right hand side of the page.
Under it want some small images to appear in certain positions along the bottom of DIV 1 (maybe even so close might have to go slightly behind DIV 1)

Problem I am getting is either:
1. The images appear in same line after DIV 1
2. Can get DIV 2 in right position but DIV 3 then appears underneath DIV 2, not on same line as it

What's the best method to achieve this?

Comment: What is the HTML and CSS you are trying now? Could you post it here after you have trimmed it down to only the bare code needed to reproduce the effect?

Comment: Please attach a jsfiddle. Or code.

Comment: Start by putting the 3 divs in your question inside of one larger div.  That will help keep them corralled better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/A5tP2/ Not sure if this is what you were looking for, but without any code I can't really help you on what you do have. But yeah.

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="oneWrap">
        <div id="one">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
           image
    </div>
   <div class="image">
           image
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: blue;
}
#oneWrap{
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
}
#one{
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background: orange;
    float: right;
}
.image{
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: purple;
    float: right;    
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the smaller divs inside of another div to be able to position them more precisely:

```
<head>
<style>
    #div1{
        float:right;
    }
    #div-helper{
        clear:both;
    }
    #div2{
        float:left;
    }
    #div3{
        float:right;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="div1">1</div>
    <div id="div-helper">
        <div id="div2">2</div>
        <div id="div3">3</div>
    </div>
</body>
```